# Trying to get a window to paint on itself when it loads

Tags: java, swing, drawing, scale

This turned out to be more difficult than i thought it would. I'm just doing some learning and poking around with the draw function. What I want is for a program to launch a window that contains, say, a rectangle. The size of that rectangle will be scaled on the size of the window (i.e. if the window is 1000px and the rectangle is set to scale at 90%, the rectangle will be 900px). I have the math figured out on how to center it and determine it's size, but through the use of stubs, i have found that using the object.getWidth() and height, etc, is returning 0 every time, completely b0rking the math for sizing.

After thinking about it for a while, i'm assuming that it is because it is trying to obtain the width and height from an object that is still being constructed. To my own logic, as long as you do the math after the build parts of the constructor, it should be fine, but alas -- i appear to be wrong.

I tried creating separate classes that creates a frame and one that makes the drawing. The drawing object accepts a JFrame as part of the constructor and attempts to draw on it. I instantiate each one separately, frame first, then drawing object (sending the frame object to it), but that doesnt seem to work either.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Per Andrew's suggestion. Here is my panel object to be added to the window

```
package scaling_test;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawing extends JPanel
{

    public MyDrawing() throws HeadlessException
    {
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        //set scaling
        int usrScale = 90;
        int scaleRef = (100 - usrScale) / 2;
        int xStart = this.getWidth() * (scaleRef / 100);
        int yStart = this.getHeight() * (scaleRef / 100);
        int width = (usrScale / 100) * this.getWidth();
        int height = (usrScale / 100) * this.getHeight(); 

        //draw square outline
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(xStart, yStart, width, height);
    }
}
```

And this is the window adding that jpanel object:

```
package scaling_test;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawThis extends JFrame
{
    MyDrawing drawing;

    public DrawThis() throws HeadlessException
    {
        drawing = new MyDrawing();
        this.add(drawing);
    }
}
```

And the Launcher

```
package scaling_test;

public class ScaleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DrawThis program = new DrawThis();
        program.setBounds(250, 250, 800, 600);
        program.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Updated panel (still doesnt work):

```
package scaling_test;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawing extends JPanel
{

    public MyDrawing() throws HeadlessException
    {
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        //set scaling
        int usrScale = 90;
        int scaleRef = (100 - usrScale) / 2;
        int xStart = this.getWidth() * scaleRef / 100;
        int yStart = this.getHeight() * scaleRef / 100;

        int width = usrScale * this.getWidth() / 100;
        int height = usrScale * this.getHeight() / 100;

        //draw square outline
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(xStart, yStart, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: the edited version works fine and does exactly what is programmed (painting a centered green filled rectangle scaled at 90% the component's size) - so what exactly is your expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use the getGraphics(...) method when the paintComponent(...) method is passed the Graphics object? Also, you should be invoking super.paintComponent(g) as the first statement in your method. I don't know why you commented it out.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we don't keep guessing what your actual code looks like.

Edit:

Did you add any display statements to see if the values used in the drawRect(...) method make any sense? Don't assume your math forumulas are correct. For one thing you need to understand how integer calculations work:

```
//        int width = (usrScale / 100) * this.getWidth();
//        int height = (usrScale / 100) * this.getHeight();
        int width = usrScale * this.getWidth() / 100;
        int height = usrScale * this.getHeight() / 100;
```

In the commented out code (usrScale / 100) = 0 since that value is converted to an integer before the multiplication is done.

Comment: i tried with and without both of the things you mentioned. it didnt change anything. you're seeing the code where i left off

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, see edit. Also next time post a proper SSCCE. We can't execute your code because it doesn't have a main() method.

Comment: i mentioned that I did add stubs to check what getWidth() and getHeight() were returning. they were  returning the correct values although repeatedly instead of once as the program seemed to be crashing -- i had to put it in the paintComponent() to get a result after being realized. Your edit on my formula yielded results that were incorrect by an entire factor. I went back and tried using doubles and then converting back to integer before sending it to the fillRect method. Same results. And I also mentioned it is be launched by a launcher. Nothing fancy. I will add it to my post...

Comment: messed that up. your formula was right. but still... same result.

Comment: i'll go back and reattack the formulas while revisiting my order of operations. haven't had this problem before

Comment: Well, it worked fine for me with the code I gave you (the x, y values where wrong for the same reason but I'll let you fix that). Also, the code for a SSCCE should be in one class so we can copy/paste/compile and run the code. I don't want to clutter my machine with all your code.

Comment: i just started over and watched my math order of operations with casting. works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Do the calculations in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of a `JPanel` that is added to the `JFrame`.  The `paintComponent()` method is only called once the component is 'realized' on-screen.

Comment: i put a stub that displays the object's width... its reading a width instead of 0 now, but still doesn't seem to be displaying

Comment: Did you persist in using a `JFrame` (which does not have a `paintComponent(Graphics)` method) or a `JPanel` (which does)?

Answer (score -1):

It's a little tricky without seeing your code, but one option is to setPreferredSize(x, y); on the JFrame, then call pack(); Afterwards, you can do your checks for window size.

Comment: no - this answer in wrong for several reasons: a) random method calling without understanding what's going wrong is always bad. b) don't never-ever call setXX (XX == min/max/pref) in application code. Instead implement getXXSize on DrawPanel if appropriate (here it might or might not be, depending on OPs intention) c) in this example there is no reason to prefer pack over setBounds: both "realize" the frame, that is locations/widths of all components in the container hierarchy are set.

Comment: Wow, being downvoted is surprisingly painful, although I think I misinterpreted the question, so it may have been justified. But anyway, why shouldn't setPreferredSize be called, seemingly ever? Isn't all code "application code"? So why is the method there at all?

Comment: sorry for causing pain, but well ... incorrect answers are incorrect answers ;-) As to the why-not-use, see http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingLabsImperialRules (looks terrible due to java.net migration). As to all-is-application: not really, there's framework code with slightly different rules. As to why it's there: can't know, maybe as a last resort? Actually, it the method _is_ used in ui-delegate code for compound components (I think one is xxComboBoxUI, but don't nail, didn't check right now)